# Retrieving String with single quotes from database and storing in Perl

Tags: perl, special-characters

I have a SQL query

```
select name from Employee
```

Output :

```
Sharma's
```

How can I store this output in perl string.

I tried below :

```
$sql =qq {select Name from Employee};
$Arr = &DataBaseQuery( $dbHandle, $sql );
$name = $Arr;
```

But when I print $name I get output as

```
 Sharma::s
```

How can I store the single quote in the $name.

Comment: What version of perl are you using?  What's in `DataBaseQuery()`?

Comment: More code is needed to answer your query. What mechanisms are you using to query your database?

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, non of standard DBI/DBD exibits behavior you listed, in my experience.
- Without knowing details of what `DataBaseQuery()` does it's impossible to answer conclusively, but a plausible theory can be formed:

  Apostrophe is a valid package separator in Perl, equivalent to "`::`".

  Reference: [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)

  > The old package delimiter was a single quote, but double colon is now the preferred delimiter, in part because it's more readable to humans, and in part because it's more readable to emacs macros. It also makes C++ programmers feel like they know what's going on--as opposed to using the single quote as separator, which was there to make Ada programmers feel like they knew what was going on. Because the old-fashioned syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility, if you try to use a string like "This is $owner's house" , you'll be accessing $owner::s ; that is, the $s variable in package owner , which is probably not what you meant. Use braces to disambiguate, as in "This is ${owner}'s house" .

  ```
  perl -e 'package A::B; $A::B=1; 1;
           package main; 
           print "double-colon: $A::B\n"; 
           print "apostrophe: $A'"'"'B\n";'
  double-colon: 1
  apostrophe: 1
  ```

  I have a strong suspicion something within your own libraries inside `DataBaseQuery()` call was written to be "smart" and to convert apostrophes to double-colons because of this.
- If you can't figure out root cause, you can always do one of the following:

  1. Write your own DB wrapper
  2. Assuming your text isn't likely to contain "`::`", run a regex to fix `s#::#'#g;` on all results from `DataBaseQuery()` (likely, in a function serving as a wrapper-replacement for `DataBaseQuery()`)